# LARAVEL: I want to import informations from another table and add it to the registration Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, forms

I created a new database Departements which contain two rows (id,name).
I want to import the information from the database and make it into a dropdown list on the registration form

As you can see from the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBZBq.png) below I added the select tag on the `register.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group-row">
    <label for="departements" class="col-md-4 control-label text-md-right">Départements :</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="departements" id="departements" class="form-control">
            @foreach($departements as $departement)
                <option value="{{ $departement ->id }}">{{ $departement ->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have already set the relation between users and departements.
Departement [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6bZO.png):

```
class Departement extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['name'];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

User [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTle0.png):

```
public function departements()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Departement');
}
public function HasAnydepartement($departements)
{
    if($this—>departements()->whereIn('name',$departements)->first())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function Hasdepartement($departement)
{
    if($this->departements()->where('name',$departement)->first())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I used the `App\Departement` on the register controller.

My problem is that even I used the `App\Departement` they show me this error:

> Undefined variable: departements (View: C:\Users\tchic\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\anapec\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

this is my register controller where i have the error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use App\Departement;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $departements=Departement::all();
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'prenom' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     * @return \App\Departement
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $departements=Departement::all();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'departement' => $data['departement'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

If someone can help me to understand where I can define the departements variable on the Register controller that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please inline your code using the proper markdown formatting, unless it is excessively long. For short and relevant code snippets it is best to include them in the question, not a link to a screenshot.

Comment: okey thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I have made an answer but there are a couple other things you should consider. Naming conventions are important. They can convey meaning to other developers just from the way you capitalize things. ```public function Hasdepartement``` does not meet [psr-12 standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) and should be named ```hasDepartement```.

Comment: Furthermore, you call ```$departements=Departement::all();``` in both the validator and create methods of your controller, and they are never referenced and thus should be removed.

Comment: Also, as a quick tip, in your hasAnyDepartement and hasDepartement methods, you can use the [exists()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#aggregates) method, and skip the if statments like so ```return $this—>departements()->whereIn('name',$departements)->exists();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things.

I am assuming you are using the default auth scaffolding. If you look into the `RegistersUsers` trait on your `RegistrationController` you will see that laravel is using the `showRegistrationForm` method to display the registration form. In your `RegistrationController` class you need to override this method to display your custom registration form. You can do this like so:

```
   /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $departements = Departement::all();
        return view('auth.register', [ 'departements' => $departments ]);
    }
```

Secondly, you will need to customize the blade file located at `./resources/views/auth/register.blade.php`. Since you only provided the snippet for the dropdown, I will inline it into a default `auth.register` blade file here.

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group-row">
        <label for="departements" class="col-md-4 control-label text-md-right">Départements :</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="departements" id="departements" class="form-control">
                @foreach($departements as $departement)
                    <option value="{{ $departement ->id }}">{{ $departement ->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define *$departements* from the loop in the view or pass it from controller? If not, assuming you have *user* passed in the view try this.

```
@foreach($user->departements() as $departement)
```

Comment: Undefined variable: user (View: C:\Users\tchic\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\anapec\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)